# How to rerun a ngFor loop after its variable's value has been changed in the component?

Tags: html, node.js, angular, ngfor

I'm trying to make a Github Search app and have used a ngFor loop to display search data. As I type the value the value of UARR changes but no changes are made to the DOM.
Initially also as I enter one character it show the result instantly but subsequent keydowns have no effect on the HTML DOM. I'm confused and looked everywhere for an answer but it was of no avail.
How can I possibly rerun ngFor loop each time the value of uarr changes?

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="username" name="username" (keyup)="searchUser()" >
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

<div *ngIf="uarr" >
  <ul *ngFor="let data of uarr" class="list-unstyled" >
        <li>
              <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                  <a href="#" >
                    <img class="github-avatar" src="{{data.avatar_url}}" >
                  </a>
                  <div class="caption">
                    <h3 class="text-center">{{ data.login }}</h3>
                  </div>

                </div>
              </div>
        </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The componentcode:

```
    import { Component  } from '@angular/core';
import { GithubService } from '../services/git.services';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';


//import { user } from '../models/gitusers';

@Component({
    selector: 'searchform',
    templateUrl: 'search.component.html',
    providers:[GithubService]
  })


export class SearchformComponent  {
    users :  any;
    uarr: any[] = [];
    username: string;

  //  @Output() userUpdated: EventEmitter<user> = new EventEmitter<user>();

    constructor(private _githubService: GithubService) {

      }

    searchUser() {
      this._githubService.updateUser(this.username);

      console.log(this.username);
        this._githubService.getUser().subscribe(user => {
        this.users = user.items;
        for (var i in this.users) {
          this.uarr.push(this.users[i]); }
        });
        console.log(this.uarr);

    }
/*
      ngOnInit() {

           if (this.user) {
               this.user.user = false;
               this.getUserInformation();
           }

       }

    getUserInformation() {
        if (this.user.userName && this.user.userName.length > 0) {

            this._githubService.getUser().subscribe(user => {
                this.user.user = user;
              //  this.userUpdated.emit(this.user);
            },
                (err) => {
                    console.log('err:' + err);
                    this.user.user = false;
                },
                () => console.log('Done')
            );



            this._githubService.getRepos().subscribe(repos => {
                // console.log(repos);
                this.user.repos = repos;
              //  this.userUpdated.emit(this.user);
            },
                (err) => {
                    console.log('err:' + err);
                    this.user.user = false;
                },
                () => console.log('Done')
            );

        }
    }*/
}
```

The Services Code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';

import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
const API_URL = environment.apiUrl;




@Injectable()
export class GithubService {
    private userName = "matt";
    private client_id = '3198278eb6fb7788fa1e';
    private client_secret = 'd6b3cf6265f7997f110ec1450246e7157d055a8f';

    constructor(private _http: Http) {
        console.log('Github Service Ready.');
    }

    getUser() {
        if (this.userName) {
            return this._http.get(API_URL + this.userName + '&client_id=' + this.client_id + '&client_secret=' + this.client_secret)
                .pipe(
                  map(res => res.json()),
                  catchError(this.handleError));
        }
    }

    getRepos() {
        if (this.userName) {
            return this._http.get(API_URL + this.userName + '/repos')
                 .pipe(
                  map(res => res.json()),
                  catchError(this.handleError));
        }

    }
    updateUser(username: string) {
        this.userName = username;
        console.log(this.userName);
    }

    private handleError(error: any) {

        if (error.status === 401) {
            return Observable.throw(error.status);
        } else {
            return Observable.throw(error.status || 'Server error');
        }
    }
}
```

Some of the functions in the services are redundant and for future use.
Should I remove the Exception handling code to  decrease the size of the app.
**Thank You.**

Comment: If `uarr` is defined as a property in the component and that property changes ... Angular's change detection will automatically rerun the ngFor and re-display the new values.

If that is not working ... there may be something else wrong in the code. Could you show your component code?

Comment: Can you show us where you assign the values to `this.uarr` in your TS?

Comment: Sure I'm adding.

Comment: @DeborahK Mam can you please have a look now. Thanks.

Comment: @DeborahK Pardon me. I've updated it to the class code.

Comment: Is this `console.log(this.uarr);` displaying the correct data?

Comment: Yes. I finally worked it out. Used a tuple instead of an array. Thanks for the support.